# Como pegar o nome do arquivo atual em python

Tags: python

Fala povo,
Estou fazendo um criador de códigos para sqlite em python.

Queria saber se há alguma forma de pegar o nome do arquivo atual para poder passar direto na função.

atualmente passo o nome por parâmetros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você tem diversas opções na verdade. Dessas apresento-lhe três:

```
import os    
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

```
import sys
print (sys.argv[0])]
```

```
print (__file__)
```

***Existe uma [discussão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152963/get-the-name-of-current-script-with-python) interessante no SO a respeito dos prós e contras do uso de cada uma. Vale a pena consultar.***

Onde:

- `__file__` é o arquivo atualmente em execução, conforme detalhado na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-43):

> `__file__` é o nome do caminho do arquivo a partir do qual o módulo foi carregado, se foi carregado de um arquivo. O `__file__`atributo pode
>   estar faltando para certos tipos de módulos, como módulos C que estão
>   vinculados estaticamente ao interpretador; para módulos de extensão
>   carregados dinamicamente a partir de uma biblioteca compartilhada, é o
>   nome do caminho do arquivo de biblioteca compartilhada.

- `sys.argv[0]`(requer importação `sys)` é o nome do script que foi chamado
     a partir da linha de comando e pode ser um caminho absoluto, conforme
     detalhado na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> `argv[0]` é o nome do script (depende do sistema operacional se esse é um
>   nome de caminho completo ou não). Se o comando foi executado usando a
>   opção `-c` de linha de comando para o intérprete, `argv[0]` será definido para a string '`-c`'. Se nenhum nome de script foi passado para o
>   interpretador Python, `argv[0]` é a string vazia.

As informações que compõe essa resposta foram [retiradas daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514032/9305064). Agradeço ao usuário [Yoel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903832/yoel).